# I have been trying to get my background image to show up but i just can't seem to do so. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Tags: html, css

This is the code that I am using in my html. I know i have linked my style sheet properly because the rest of the styling works. So I have no idea why this specific background image just does not work in my code. It does not display anywhere on the webpage when I try to load it up so i honestly have no idea what is wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
     <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
     </head>
     <body>
      <header class="showcase">`
      </header>
     </body>
    </html>
```

This is in my css. I have triple checked that the name of the image correlates and it is definitely in a images folder in my main folder but I just do not understand why this is not working. I am a bit new but I am still confused.

```
.showcase {
 width: 100%;
 height: 93vh;
 position: relative;
 background-image: url('../images/background.png') no-repeat center center/cover;
 }
```

Comment: Typo (more or less). You seem to be giving a value suitable for the `background` shorthand property to the `background-image` property.

Comment: That still did not work. I am so lost with this. In the folder I first started using I have other code which I thought somewhere might be the problem so I decided to open up another page with only the code at the top and still it does not work. I even tried moving the image out of the secondary folder and changing it in the css but nothing. I really have no idea what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help I managed to sort it out and it is working fine now. I removed the `../` from my `background-image: url('../images/background.png');` and I changed my `center/cover` to just `cover` as the second `center` was causing it to not work. My new code now looks like this and is working perfectly.

```
.showcase {
 width: 100%;
 height: 93vh;
 position: relative;
 background-image: url('images/background.png');
 background: no-repeat center cover;
 }
```

Comment: Yep, actually, as I was rearranging my files in my USB with my codes, I was forced to make the file paths just as you were. Sounds Great!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you are putting the values `no-repeat center center/cover` under the `background-image` property, instead of the `background` property. It should actually look like so:

```
.showcase {

    width: 100%;
    height: 93vh;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('.../images/background.png');
    background: no-repeat center center/cover;
}
```

That should work. If not, try changing the position to `absolute` or `auto`. If all that doesn't work, try changing the `center/cover` to just `center` or `cover`.